# How to add base64 data to FormData so that it's uploaded as binary

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, base64, image-uploading, form-data

I have a API source of image data in base64 format. I'm trying to upload it as normal binary upload.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) I can see that my problem is, given the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) is available, reduced to making binary Blob from base64:

```
var content = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABUUAAAI/...'; // the image
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "image/png,base64"});

formData.append("image", blob);
```

How can I do this safely (=avoid wild unicode strings)?

Comment: put atob(content) into the Blob instead of just content